# Mvc 4 customize routes

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website that any user can have few companies. 
I want to make custom rote where the company will be part of the route:

```
~/{CompanyName}/{Controller}/{Action}/Id
```

Can I do it? how?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a route

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "CompanyRoute",
  url: "{companyName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

Then define your action methods with a `companyName` parameter

```
public ActionResult Index(string companyName)
{
  ....

public ActionResult Details(string companyName, int ID)
{
  ....
```

so `/Acme/Home/Details/4` would call the `Details` method, passing "Acme" and 4